# Grafana with ElasticSearch Where Query

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I am using Grafana server with ElasticSearch to monitor my Micro-services architecture which consists of 15-20 Services.

Now currently the issue I am facing that for each service, I have to create a new index in elasticsearch as I can only specify DATETIME field in elasticsearch. So what should I do to move everything to one Index and add a field in index say service name / service id which is service identifier. So how do I specify this column in Grafana.? I mean I want to use a where clause in Grafana to filter out the documents based on service name / service id so that I just have to create one index & not separate index for every service?